# increase bubble size in geom_point, not label. Using ggplot2 + gganimate + ggrepel

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate, ggrepel

I have a pretty simple animation using gganimate and geom_point showing increases per year regarding two categories.

My issue is that I want bubble size to increase along time but the label keep same size.

reproducible example code:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~year, ~total, ~amount, ~type, ~cumtotal, ~cumamount,
  2016L,   14.3,    28.6,   "A",      14.3,       28.6,
  2017L,    153,    39.8,   "A",       167,       68.4,
  2018L,   25.2,    48.2,   "A",       192,        117,
  2011L,    0.2,     2.3,   "B",       192,        119,
  2012L,   17.8,      32,   "B",       210,        151,
  2013L,   11.9,      78,   "B",       222,        229,
  2014L,   10.7,     158,   "B",       233,        387,
  2015L,   16.8,     174,   "B",       250,        562,
  2016L,     20,     114,   "B",       270,        676,
  2017L,   58.7,     305,   "B",       328,        980,
  2018L,   33.8,     836,   "B",       362,       1817
  )
library(randomcoloR)
n <- length(df$type %>% unique())
palette <- unname(distinctColorPalette(n))

ggplot(df, aes(cumtotal, cumamount, size = cumtotal, colour = type, label =  type)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.75, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = palette) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(2, 20)) + # added this because I need the bubble to have a minimal size
  scale_y_log10() +
  geom_text_repel(segment.color = "slategrey",
                  nudge_y = 0.05,
                  angle        = 0,
                  vjust        = -5,
                  segment.size = 0.2) +
  labs(title = 'Year: {frame_time}', x = 'Total', y = 'Freq') +
  transition_time(year) +
  ease_aes('linear')
```

Seems that bubble size is not moving and, in addition, label is big (and not size moving either) but the main issues is to fix label to the usual size and keep that way along animation.

[image]

Desired outcome should be something like this:

[image]

Comment: where come's this function from? Please include all required packages. Have you tried to move the `size = cumtotal` into `aes` in `geom_point`?

Comment: library(randomcoloR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `size = cumtotal, colour = type` in `geom_point`. Didn't know where `distinctColorPalette()` is from.

```
library(ggrepel)
library(gganimate)
ggplot(df, aes(cumtotal, cumamount, group = type, label =  type)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = type, size = cumtotal), alpha = 0.75, show.legend = FALSE) +
  # scale_colour_manual(values = palette) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(2, 20)) + # added this because I need the bubble to have a minimal size
  scale_y_log10() +
  geom_text_repel(segment.color = "slategrey",
                  nudge_y = 0.05,
                  angle        = 0,
                  vjust        = -5,
                  segment.size = 0.2) +
  labs(title = 'Year: {frame_time}', x = 'Total', y = 'Freq') +
  transition_time(year) +
  ease_aes('linear')
```

[image]

Comment: library(randomcoloR)

Comment: why label disappeared and runs back towards point A and then again to point B? IMgine it with more than 10 points. A label dance

Comment: your answer leads to a subtle wrong chart. The labels abandon their bubble back and forth markus

Comment: @useRj Added `group = type` in `ggplot()`.